# Components are not rendering while using .map() on array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

The component renders as it should at first. After refreshing the page then does not render. Again if I change the key to different value  it works and after refreshing page its gone again.

My component

```
const Book = ({ membersDetail }) => {

     const history = useHistory();

     const takeToBookNav = () => {

        history.push("/recordbook/booknav");

     };

return (

  <div className="book">

   {membersDetail.map(({ name, phoneNumber }) => (

   <div className="select-members">

       <div key={phoneNumber} classname="member" onClick={takeToBookNav}>{name}</div>

   </div>

   ))}

   </div>

  );

};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({

   membersDetail: selectMembersList,

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Book);
```

MEMBER_REDUCER

```
import MemberActionTypes from "./members-action.type";

const ININTIAL_STATE = {

  members: null,

  errorMessage: "",

  isGettingMembers: false,

  isAddingMembers: false,

  isRemovingMembers: false,

};

const memberReducer = (state = ININTIAL_STATE, action) => {

switch (action.type) {

  case MemberActionTypes.GET_MEMBER_START:

    return {

       ...state,

       isGettingMembers: true,

    };

 case MemberActionTypes.GET_MEMBER_SUCESS:

     return {

       ...state,

       members: action.payload,

       errorMessage: "",

   };

 case MemberActionTypes.GET_MEMBER_FAILURE:

     return {

       ...state,

       errorMessage: action.payload,

       isAddingMembers: false,

       isRemovingMembers: false,

       isGettingMembers: false,

  };

 default:

    return state;

  }

};

export default memberReducer;
```

SAGAs

```
export function* gettingMembers() {

  try {

      const membersList = yield getMembers();

      yield put(getMembersSucess(membersList));

      } catch (error) {

        yield put(getMembersFailure(error));

       }

     }

export function* getInintialMembersList() {

     yield put(getMembersStart());

}

export function* onSigningInSucess() {

   yield takeLatest(
 
    UserActionTypes.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_SUCESS,

    getInintialMembersList

  );

}

export function* onGettingMembers() {

    yield takeLatest(MemberActionTypes.GET_MEMBER_START, gettingMembers);

}
```

FIREBASE

```
//members data to firebase

const database = firebase.database(); //gets the database

const membersRef = database.ref("members");

export const createMember = (memberCredentials) => {

//pushing the object to the reference members

  membersRef.push(memberCredentials);

};

//get array of members from firebase

export const getMembers = () => {

  const membersList = [];

  membersRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {

  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

  const item = childSnapshot.val();

  item.key = childSnapshot.key;

  membersList.push(item);

});

 console.log(membersList);

});
 
return membersList;

};
```

firebase DATABASE is like

myproject-default-rtdb

| -members

```
 |-MaApwTgulOH0bl1zSH

       | -name: "Jhon Doe"
       |-phoneNumber: "984215789"
```

Thank you for Helping.

Comment: You need to use the `key`-attribute on the top-most component, which in your case is `<div className="select-members">` and not `<div key={phoneNumber} classname="member" onClick={takeToBookNav}>`.

Comment: I did what u said still having same issue

Comment: `   <div className="select-members">
        {membersDetail.map(({ name, phoneNumber }) => (
          <div key={phoneNumber} classname="member" onClick={takeToBookNav}>
            {name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>`

Comment: My next guess would be that `membersDetail` actually is empty after a refresh. Did you try debugging it, to see if it actually has a value?

Comment: Actually I should have mentioned it with the question.
I have double checked it again
it consoles an empty array but with value.
there is no option to upload image here

Comment: I have reputation less than 10.

Comment: membersDetail consoles before refresh like
>[{...}]
    >0: {name: "john doe", phoneNumber: "984412", key:"ASHDJSJ"}
    length: 1
    >_proto_: Array(0)

membersDetail after refresh consoles like
>[]
   >0: {name: "john doe", phoneNumber: "984456654" , key:"ASHDJSJ"}
    length: 1
    >_proto_: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

The code `const membersList = yield getMembers();` does not make any sense since `getMembers` in your firebase code is not a generator.

Since the [value event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#value-event) triggers whenever something changes you should have that event listener dispatch a redux action to update the redux state and your saga can just be deleted. Your saga looks like code from a classic api where you fetch data but firebase doesn't work like that.

In your component you can start and stop listening to updates from members but you won't fetch data like with classic REST api.

So your `getMembers` can just be something like the following listenToMembers:

```
//your firebase code
let listening = false;
const onNewMembers = (() => {
  let allMembers = [];
  return (snapshot) => {
    //concat new members to existing members
    allMembers = allMembers.concat(
      snapshot.map(function (childSnapshot) {
        const item = childSnapshot.val();
        item.key = childSnapshot.key;
        return item;
      })
    );
    //store is your redux store
    store.dispatch(getMembersSucess(allMembers));
  };
})(); //IIFE that has all members
export const listenToMembers = () => {
  //check if we are already listening to members
  if (listening) {
    return;
  }
  listening = true;
  membersRef.on('value', onNewMembers);
};
//you can call this function if you're no longer interested in
//  changes in members
export const stopListenToMembers = () => {
  membersRef.off('value', onNewMembers);
};
```

I have not worked with firebase much but I think you should [set allMembers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) first when your app starts or use [onSnapShot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) instead of `.on('value'`.